# Python: Using grid with button array

Tags: python, tkinter

First of all I would like to say hello to all members as this is my first post here, Hello All.

Problem:
I am trying to get grid to give me a block of 4 buttons from a list of names. Two at the top and two below.

My code:

```
self.button_names = ["New","Open","About","Exit"]
        for item in self.button_names:
            button = tk.Button(self.button_frame,text=item)
            button.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks h...

Comment: And, what is the question? What is not working? See [mcve].

Comment: Buttons are stacking on top of each other

Comment: You are assigning them same position in the grid, so they would. You can instead try `for number, item in enumerate(self.button_names):` and then use the `number` against the `row` or `column` argument to `button.grid`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained a bit more. I am new to coding and have been using pack() much to often I think. I know that I am stacking the buttons on top of each other in the example given, but this is where I am stuck. An example of using the code with enumerate would be of great help to me. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `row=0, column=0` arguments according to the button number.

```
self.button_names = ["New","Open","About","Exit"]
row_size, col_size = 5, 10
for btn_no, btn_name in enumerate(self.button_names):
    button = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text=btn_name)
    button.grid(row=btn_no*row_size, column=btn_no*col_size)
```

Vary the adjustments according to your needs.